# Retrieving data from an SFTP server using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch for retrieving a file from a remote machine by SFTP. Here is the code

```
public class TestSFTPinJava {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("username", "sftp.abc.com", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword("password");
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            System.out.println("Directory:" + sftpChannel.pwd());
            sftpChannel.cd("remoteDirectory/");
            System.out.println("Directory after cd:" + sftpChannel.pwd());
            sftpChannel.get("remote-data.txt");

            sftpChannel.put("C:\\Users\\mona\\Documents\\local-copy.txt");
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have two questions:

- `sftpChannel.get("remote-data.txt");` throws an exception:

  > no such file
  >      at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
  >      at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1750)
  >      at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1020)
  >      at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:995)
  >      at TestSFTPinJava.main(TestSFTPinJava.java:29)
- I am not sure how to specify the location in my local system where the file will be saved.
  `sftpChannel.put("C:\\Users\\mona\\Documents\\localCopy.txt");` does not look right to me.

Please help with suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: Which JSch version are you using? The one linked by Andre has different line numbers (e.g. no throwStatusError in line 1750).

Comment: jsch-0.1.44 is the JSch version. I am not sure why sftpChannel.get("remote-data.txt"); is throwing a no such file exception. Would you suggest anything?

Comment: This was mainly to find the right line in the source fitting to your stacktrace. Our 1750 corresponds to [line 1741 in the grepcode version](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#1741).

Comment: The server was returning the error message "no such file" :-/

Comment: Do you think I am using the updated JSch version? Also any suggestion from your side is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could issue `sftpChannel.ls()`, and print the resulting Vector. Maybe this helps a bit.

Comment: I don't think it is a version problem here, this was just to [look up the line number in my version of the code](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/blob/d60c96cb5f1a23cc54140a4f0eee1f05c028e157/src/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#L1750).

Comment: I just ran your program (replacing username, password and server by mine, and `sftpChannel.get("remote-data.txt");` by `sftpChannel.get("remote-data.txt", "downloaded-data.txt");`, and it worked fine.

Comment: OK that worked for me, now I can download the data. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concerning your point 1, I suspect that the default directory after connecting is not what you expect. Try using an absolute remote path. Does `sftpChannel.pwd()` return the directory the file `remote-data.txt` is in on the remote machine ?

Concerning your point 2, looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#290 one sees that there is the following method in `ChannelSftp`:

```
 public void put(String src, String dst)
```

which indeed has a source and destination file name argument.

I guess you had already a look the Jsch sftp example at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I sftpChannel.pwd() returns the directory in which my remote-data.txt file is present. But even after that I get the same exception. I have modified my codes and here it is

Comment: and if you use the absolute path with `get` ?

Comment: No doesnot work using the absolute path with the get. Also I have edited my codes in the question to include the modified. It still throws the same exception.Please suggest !

Comment: Could it be a permission problem ? Can you get the file with another (command line / graphical ) sftp client program ?

Comment: Yes I can get that using graphical sftp client! SO it is not permission problem

Comment: Also it works till the line before get. Here is what console shows      Directory:/
Directory after cd:/remoteDirectory
2: no such file
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1750)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1020)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:995)
 at SFTPCrashData.main(SFTPCrashData.java:55)

Comment: Just a hint: I created a [JSch Javadoc with comments](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/), so you don't have to guess from the source code which method is the right one. (@mona, too.)

Comment: I am looking through that and its helpful. But would you like to suggest what will be better to use in my case, i.e. I want to download the remote-data.txt file and save it in my local system. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple example of app.
I get file from remote server (from /tmp/qtmp) and save it in local machine in the current path

```
package connector;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class Fetcher {

    public void fetchFile(String username, String host, String passwd) throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException {
        JSch conn = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        session = conn.getSession(username, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(passwd);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();

        ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        //change folder on the remote server
        channel.cd("/tmp/qtmp");

        InputStream in = channel.get("testScp");
        // set local file
        String lf = "OBJECT_FILE";
        FileOutputStream tergetFile = new FileOutputStream(lf);

        // read containts of remote file to local
        int c;
        while ( (c= in.read()) != -1 ) {
            tergetFile.write(c);
        } 

        in.close();
        tergetFile.close();

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue, i was trying to get some files from a server where everything was fine, but i was getting always this error:

```
sftpChannel.get("fil1.txt","file1.txt")

error message: 

2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:913)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:873)
...
```

I was listing properly all the elements of the directory by using

```
java.util.Vector v1 = sftpChannel.ls(dir);
```

I think that was that confused me, that i was able to read the content of the directory by using the ls command,  when you want to get / put files make sure you move first by using "cd".

The solution was to use the next command to move to the directory that contains my files using a simple cd command:

```
sftpChannel.cd(dir);
```

Hope this helps, i took my sometime to figure it out. jojo.

Lessons learned:

1.- ls can read any directory no matter if you are not inside of it. 
2.- To get and put files always make sure you are in the directory that contains the files by using cd.